# TabView doesn't show text on first view SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

The problem: When I lunch the app, the first tabview doesn't display the name below. I have to go to another view and come back for it to show. Why?

```
struct MotherView : View {

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if viewRouter.currentPage == "onboardingView" {
            OnboardingView()
        } else if viewRouter.currentPage == "homeView" {
            TabView {
                HomeView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                        Text("Menu")
                }

                SettingsView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                        Text("Order")
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just guess, because you didn't show us the code of your HomeView.
Nevertheless I guess in your HomeView you have this line `.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)`.

Remove it and it will work as expected.

Comment: loooool what a pro, that's exactly what I had, removed it and works. Thanks